# Executing on click function on ids and names assigned through jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am sending a part of html code from jquery in the following way

```
htmlCode1 = "<div class='txt_center'>\
<input type='button'  class='btn_view b widthauto' value='Add'  name='addShortlist'\ style='cursor:pointer;'";\
htmlCode1 += " id=add"+this.id+" >\
</div>";
```

Here I am assigning an id and a name in the html and want to execute certain functions on clicking these ids, but somehow my onclick functions arent getting executed. What is the solution for this?

I am calling the onclick functions as:

```
$("[name='addShortlist']").click(
    function()
    {
        alert("here");
        return false;
    }
);
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML up. Your selector looks a bit whack. What are the elements with the attribute name?

Comment: i have assigned "addShortlist" as a name and i am trying to execute a function on an onclick event

Comment: you need to out the single quotes around the id, ie `id='add"+this.id"' >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for registering event handlers to dynamically added content is **event delegation**, using either the `.on()` (jQuery 1.7+) or `.delegate()` functions. The basic principle is that you bind an event handler to a static element (worst case, the entire document) that will execute the callback function only when the event originated from an element matching the selector.

The general code would look something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '[name="addShortlist"]', function() {
    alert("here");
    return false;
});
```

That way, whenever you click on an element matching the selector `[name="addShotlist"]` - event if it was added after that code was executed - it will still execute the callback function.

For more information, read the section titled **Direct and delegated events** on the documentation for [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

UPDATE

If you're using a version of jQuery without access to **any** of the event delegation functions (i.e. prior to jQuery 1.3 when they added `.live()`) the only option you really have is to do the following:

```
$(function() {
    function handleClick() {
        alert("here");
        return false;
    }

    function bindClicks() {
        $("[name='addShortlist']").unbind('click', handleClick).click(handleClick);
    }

    $("#test-button').click(function(e) {
        // dynamically add some content
        bindClicks();
    });
});
```

That turns the anonymous callback function into a named function (so you can pass a reference to it), wraps the binding of the event handler into a function (so you can call it easily from lots of locations), and adds a call to `.unbind()` to remove any identical event handlers from previously existing elements (ones that existed the last time the function was called), before re-binding the event handler to **all** elements that now match the selector.

Comment: I am using jquery version 1.2.6, anything I can use there?

Comment: If you're constrained to that version then you can use .live instead of .on

Comment: The `.live()` function - the earliest function I know of to provide event delegation functionality - wasn't added until 1.3, so you're kind of out of luck. Is there any reason you can't update to a newer version?

Comment: Anthony Grist's is correct - you should consider accepting this as the answer.

Comment: upgrading to a newer version might be risky as there are many other things running

Comment: @user1085195 If you can't update and use event delegation, you're left with unbinding/re-binding the event handler every time you add dynamic content to make sure any new elements matching the selector get the event handler added to them. Answer has been updated accordingly. That said, I would ***strongly*** suggest that you update to a newer version, and solve any problems that arise with your other code.